# Prevent field of JSON object to be excluded, while serializing one-to-many relationship in springboot

Tags: json, spring-boot

i have 2 classes , one for User details and other for User fitness
all i want is to exclude **name** field from final json object of FitnessRecord class using **FitnessRecordRepository.findAll()**.
this is my json output now.

```
{
    "fitness_id": 1,
    "date_of_performance": "2018-04-06",
    "user": {
        "user_id": 1,
        "name": "Hilal Kaldane",
        "email": "hilalkaldane@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

and what i want is

```
{
    "fitness_id": 1,
    "date_of_performance": "2018-04-06",
    "user": {
        "user_id": 1,
        "email": "hilalkaldane@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

**User.class**

```
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer user_id;

@NotNull
private String name;

@NotNull
@Column(unique = true)
private String email;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
private Set<FitnessRecord> fitness_record = new HashSet<>();



//Getter and Setters are omitted
}
```

**FitnessRecord.class**

```
public class FitnessRecord {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer fitness_id;

public Integer getFitness_id() {
    return fitness_id;
}

public void setFitness_id(Integer fitness_id) {
    this.fitness_id = fitness_id;
}

@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
@ManyToOne
private User user;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date date_of_performance;
}
```

**Note:-** *I dont want to use JSON ignore on User Class, since i will be using the* **name** *field in other places such as user information retrieval*

Comment: You can use a DTO class and use [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/) to map the response from the database to it.

Comment: thankyou very much @rena . it helped a lot.

Comment: The Solution mentioned by @rena worked.

Thanks rena.

here is the working example i have implemented
[ModelMapper in SpringBoot](https://github.com/hilalkaldane/modelmapper-springboot/tree/master/modelmapper-example/src/main/java/modelmapper)